# Install Vlc 1.1 without building it from source

Tags: apt, dependencies, aptitude

I am using Ubuntu 15.04. Is there any way to install VLC version 1.1 **without** having to build it from source?

I tried these method but I was stuck in endless loop of unmet dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg -i vlc_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb # I have downloaded offline deb package (but not its dependencies)
sudo aptitude build-dep vlc
```

and also

```
sudo dpkg -i vlc_1.1.0-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

In above methods, all the time I was asked to remove vlc1.1 and it dependency is never met.

*FAILURE OF APT-GET/APTITUTE/DPKG ?*

(*200 bounties for any one who solves this*)

Comment: why such an ancient version?  what's wrong with the vlc 2.2.1-3 that's in wily?  http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/vlc

Comment: @cas because I want to install old version

Comment: oh well.  i guess you'll have to learn how to install the source deps and compile a package, then.  If you're really lucky you may find a ppa containing vlc 1.1 for wily.